# Select a node based on an ID-attribute from a value of another ref-attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this pseudo-xml:

```
<list>
    <entry id="1">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <link ref="2"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2">
        <item>Item 2</item>
    </entry>
</list>
```

I want to get the `<item>`-node in a template selected by an attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:value-of select="/list/entry[@id=./@ref]/item"/>
</xsl:template>
```

When I enter `/list/entry[@id='2']/item` manually, it works, but I need it kind of dynamic.
When I debug it, `./@ref` (and also just `@ref`) are the right value of `2`.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this:

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:value-of select="/list/entry[@id=./@ref]/item"/>
</xsl:template>
```

doesn't work is because the xpath is trying to select `entry` when the `id` attribute equals the `ref` attribute. (You would need to use `current()/@ref`.)

However, I would suggest using `xsl:key` to create a key of all `entry` elements based on `id` attribute...

**XML Input**

```
<list>
    <entry id="1">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <link ref="2"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2">
        <item>Item 2</item>
    </entry>
</list>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="entries" match="entry" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="link">
    <test>
      <xsl:value-of select="key('entries',@ref)/item"/>      
    </test>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<list>
   <entry id="1">
      <item>Item 1</item>
      <test>Item 2</test>
   </entry>
   <entry id="2">
      <item>Item 2</item>
   </entry>
</list>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `current()` works best for me. And thanks for the key-solution, I'll, get into that tomorrow :)